# Find all natural $x,y,z$ solutions for $2^x-2^y=2016^z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all natural $x,y,z$ solutions for $2^x-2^y=2016^z$

I found this problem in a contest archive and I've managed to find one solution $(x,y,z)=(11,5,1)$. I think it's important that the congruencies after $2^5$ start repeating...
$2^5\equiv32$ (mod $2016$)
$2^6\equiv64$ (mod $2016$)
$2^7\equiv128$ (mod $2016$)
$2^8\equiv256$ (mod $2016$)
$2^9\equiv512$ (mod $2016$)
$2^{10}\equiv1024$ (mod $2016$)
$2^{11}\equiv32$ (mod $2016$)
...
and obviously $2^x$ and $2^y$ must have the same remainder mod $2016$. I don't think there are more solutions, but I'm having trouble proving it. Any help is appreciated and I apologize for the problem's simplicity but I am still at high-school level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $32\mid 2016$, $x,y\ge 5z$. So $2^{x-5z}-2^{y-5z}=63^z$.WLOG $x>y$, then $y-5z=0, y=5z$, $2^{x-y}-1=63^z$. Let $u=x-y$, $2^u-1=63^z$. The order of $2$ modulo $63$ is $6$. So $u=6v$ for some natural $v$. So we have $64^v-1=63^z$ or $(63+1)^v-1=63^z$ or
$63^v+v63^{v-1}+...+v63=63^z$. One can deduce that $v=z=1$, $u=6$, so $x=y+6$, $y=5z=5, x=y+6v=11$.

Answer (score 0):

You have: $1 = 2^{x-y} - 2^{5z-y}\cdot 3^{2z}\cdot 7^z$. This means $y=5z$. There are some more work to do. I left it as a hint and you may continue.